# Get-ChildItem equivalent of DIR /X

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

How do I show a directory listing in 8.3 notation in PowerShell?

Comment: My requirement for 8.3 names came about because I wanted to use DEBUG.exe to investigate a file at the byte level. (Of course I could do it in a CMD shell instead.) Unfortunately, I then discovered that 64-bit Windows does not have DEBUG.exe anymore.  So I now need to start a new question on what's the best substitute for DEBUG.exe.

Comment: This is why it is good to tell why you want to do it, not just what. One possibility: [Windows IT Pro: Get Hex Dumps of Files in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/get-hex-dumps-files-powershell).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Excellent!  GC -Encoding Byte is useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use WMI:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object{
    $class  = if($_.PSIsContainer) {"Win32_Directory"} else {"CIM_DataFile"}
    Get-WMIObject $class -Filter "Name = '$($_.FullName -replace '\\','\\')'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EightDotThreeFileName
}
```

Or the Scripting.FileSystemObject com object:

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object{

    if($_.PSIsContainer) 
    {
        $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).ShortPath
    }
    else 
    {
        $fso.GetFile($_.FullName).ShortPath
    }    
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` approach is much faster. As for the WMI/CIM approach: Given that `'` is a legal character in a file name, it's better to use `\`"...\`"` inside the filter, as follows (also replaced `Get-WmiObject` with `Get-CimInstance` (PSv3+)): `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $class  = if ($_.PSIsContainer) { "Win32_Directory" } else { "CIM_DataFile" } Get-CimInstance $class -Filter "Name = \`"$($_.FullName -replace '\\','\\')\`"" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EightDotThreeFileName }`

Answer (score 3):

If you install the [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) module you have the `Get-ShortPath` cmdlet and you can do:

```
dir | Get-ShortPath
```

or

```
 dir | Get-ShortPath  | select -expa shortpath
```

Comment: As admin: `choco install pscx -y`

Comment: I used it like so `(Get-ShortPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x86").ShortPath` to get `C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\Lib\100105~1.0\um\x86`.

Answer (score 0):

You attract my attention, this is not the full answer but my way to help you :

**First** : have a look to [how to Control 8dot3 naming in Windows 2008 and Windows 7](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/control-8dot3-naming-in-windows-2008-and-windows-7/).

**Second** : here is a solution to [Convert path to Dos 8.3 notation using C#](http://joelangley.blogspot.fr/2009/06/convert-path-to-dos-83-notation-using-c.html) that you can modify or use as is in PowerShell.

Comment: Interesting.  My requirement for 8.3 names came about because I wanted to use DEBUG.exe to investigate a file at the byte level. (Of course I oulcd do it in a CMD shell instead.) Unfortunately, I then discovered that 64-bit Windows does not have DEBUG.exe anymore.  So I now need to start a new question on what's the best substitute for DEBUG.exe.

Comment: What is your target using DEBUG.EXE? Have a look to WinDbg from (Debuging Tools for Window)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The ancient DEBUG.com, since DOS 1.1, is a small footprint always-there (until now) utility that could, besides disassembling Intel op code, read raw bytes in a file and load disk sectors.  No, I wasn't wanting to use it to debug any code.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could run cmd...

```
cmd /c dir /x
```

Note that get-childitem -filter matches on the short version of the filenames too!

```
get-childitem -filter *~1*
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on jpblanc's answer, here is a method that can shorten an entire path by calling the Win32 [GetShortPathName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) API:

```
function Get-ShortPathName
{
    Param([string] $path)

    $MethodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "GetShortPathNameW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetShortPathName(string pathName, System.Text.StringBuilder shortName, int cbShortName);
'@

    $Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
    $shortPath = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder(500)
    $retVal = $Kernel32::GetShortPathName($path, $shortPath, $shortPath.Capacity)
    return $shortPath.ToString()
}
```

In addition to the links cited earlier, I consulted [Dr. Scripto](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/) and [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=GetShortPathName&namespace=[All]) in writing this function.