# Illegal characters in Powershell filepath error

Tags: powershell, special-characters, filenames, ntfs

I'm trying to get a script to find and delete specific files on remote hosts. To do this the script cycles through a list of locations and file names in a couple of arrays.

One of the files I need to do this with is on called `101" "" "lyrics.vbs` but I can't find a way for it to detect the file without giving the error message `test-path : Illegal characters in path` and reference to the `""` marks.  I've searched around this and tried the solution of saving the file path into a text file and then calling it with `get-item -literalpath` but this didn't work either.  I've also tried using the backtick `` ` `` before each of the `"` in the file paths but still get the same results.  The part of the code that is used for this is:

```
 $users | ForEach-Object {
#Creating an array file locations
$filelist = @("c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101__lyrics.vbs","c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101" "" "lyrics.vbs","c$\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\101" "" "lyrics.vbs>")

   foreach ($file in $filelist)
    {
     $newfilepath = Join-Path "\\$computer\" "$file"
             if (test-path $newfilepath)
             {
             Write-Host -foregroundcolor Yellow "$newfilepath file exists"
                    try
                   {
                       Remove-Item $newfilepath -force -recurse -ErrorAction Stop
                   }
                   catch
                   {
                       Write-host -ForegroundColor red "Error while deleting $newfilepath on $computer.`n$($Error[0].Exception.Message)"

                     continue
                    }

                  Write-Host  -ForegroundColor green "$newfilepath file deleted`n"
              }

    }
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: The error message I get when adding backticks before each `"` and using `-literalpath` is:

```
test-path : Illegal characters in path.
At .\Rb.ps1:126 char:22
+                  if (test-path -literalpath $newfilepath)
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\AAZAJCMW0459\...`" `"lyrics.vbs:String) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Comment: Edit your question, and add the error messages you get with `-literalpath` and with using backticks.

Comment: Just for clarity: the filename is `101" "" "lyrics.vbs` which includes double-quote space double-quote double-quote space double-quote? My guess would be that one tool or another is introducing extra quotes. What does a directory listing of the folder show?

Comment: There's also a `>` at the end of the last string in `$filelist`

Comment: I've updated the post with the error message I get with adding backticks and -literalpath.

@richard, annoyingly 101" "" "lyrics.vbs is the file name, it's a malicious file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a later comment you say that it's a malicious file, so presumably its name was crafted to evade normal attempts to delete it.

Indeed, **`"` is not a legal filename character on NTFS on Windows, and attempts to target such a file *directly* will *fail*** - no escaping technique will help.

---

You *may* be able to gain access to the file via enumeration / wildcard matching, [obtain its short 8.3 name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001227/45375), and use *that* to delete it.

*Update: The OP has confirmed that deleting via the 8.3 file name worked.*

Comment: I finally managed to get a sample and using the short 8.3 name worked! Thank you very much mklement0

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $filelist = @("c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101__lyrics.vbs","c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101" "" "lyrics.vbs","c$\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\101" "" "lyrics.vbs>")
> ```

PowerShell fails when multiple strings are placed together. In more detail:

> ```
> "c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101" "" "lyrics.vbs"
> ```

is a syntax error. To include a double quote in a double-quoted string use the back-tick (`` ` ``) as an escape:

```
"c$\Users\$($_.Name)\101`" `"`" `"lyrics.vbs"
```

Comment: OP said he'd used backticks, but might have used them incorrectly. Nevertheless, [double quotes are illegal characters in a Windows filename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). I'd expect Windows to fail to create such a file, regardless of the tool. Maybe what looks like `"` is a Unicode look-alike, or part of an alternate data stream. Or maybe an 8.3 workaround is called for here.